# C# Loop through directories with nesting index

Tags: c#

How can I loop through directories with specified nesting index using C#?

Little example:

```
Folder1
|__Folder1.1
|  |__Folder1.1.1
|__Folder1.2

Folder2
|__Folder2.1
   |__Folder2.1.1
   |__Folder2.1.2
      |__Folder2.1.2.1
```

With max nesting index 1 we will get following directories:
*(nesting level 0)* Folder1, Folder2
*(nesing level 1)*  Folder1.1, Folder1.2, Folder2.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We might be able to help you, but you'll need to show us your work to date. What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: See `System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a recursive method using the [`Directory.GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) function:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Loop(@"c:\work", 1);
    }

    static void Loop(string root, int nestingIndex = 0)
    {
        if (nestingIndex < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(root))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(folder);
            Loop(folder, nestingIndex - 1);
        }
    }
}
```